# Exporting as JPEG with the same boundary

Tags: raster, shapefile, arcgis-pro, convert, raster-conversion

I want to export without adding those white zones. Original images, which shapefile created from, width/height value is 7062/9307, I use these numbers as exported image size. In my mind expected output should be the same as input's boundaries (black boundary), however I don't know why but application just add those white 'buffer zones'(blue boundary) as shown in 'show preview'. Is there any way for me to export this file as JPEG/PNG but with black boundary?

Note: There is a function called Export Raster, in that function we have the option to choose  'clipping geometry' with it I can specify the exact boundaries, but as you can guess in order to use that function input has to be raster file, in my case it's shapefile which vectorized from raster data.

[image]

Comment: If you have vector data Clip https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/clip.htm can be used to trim your shapefile.

Comment: But those white zones appear after I export it as JPEG, therefore I really can't use Clip function, since as a vector data, size is correct.